# Uber Cadence Local Activity Vs Side Effect

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

What are some key differences between *Local Activities* and *Side Effect*? On the surface both of them appear to be similar where Local Activity is a super set.
When should user prefer Side Effect over Local Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SideEffect` doesn't support any error handling. If it fails it essentially blocks the workflow execution (by panicing the decision task). It is also executed in the same goroutine as the workflow code.

`LocalActivity` is executed in a separate goroutine and supports error handling including automatic retries through `RetryOptions`.

So use `SideEffect` only for very short lived operations that are not expected to fail. Or if they fail it is OK to block the workflow execution. UUID generation is a good example of such operation.